# Number of days in multiple periods, minus any overlap

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate days between a list of start and finish dates minus any overlap.

```
Date A              Date B      Days taken  
01/01/2018          01/01/2018  0   
01/01/2018          05/01/2018  4   
01/01/2018          10/01/2018  9    
12/01/2018          15/01/2018  3   

Total: 16   
Total Days minus overlap: 12
```

The number of days it took to complete this project was 16 days in total. Once we take away the 4 overlapping days we are left with 12.

This is a simple example. I would like to work out the total days minus overlap over a 6-12 month period.

Initially I tried an array formula with a combination of macros to sort the data. It seemed to work out the overlap but it throws up wrong results.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($F$4:$F$234=R4),--($D$4:$D$234>$C$5:$C$235),--($C$5:$C$235<>""),($D$4:$D$234-$C$5:$C$235)-($D$4:$D$234-$D$5:$D$235)*($D$4:$D$234>$D$5:$D$235)*($D$5:$D$235<>0))
```

I then tried some VBA (my knowledge is basic). This works out every unique date between the dates.  But I do not want date A to be a included as a day, for instance;

Date A: 01/01/2018
Date B: 05/01/2018

This should total 4 days.

```
Option Explicit
Function UniqueDayCount(rStart As Range, rEnd As Range) As Long
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim vStart As Variant, vEnd As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

vStart = rStart
vEnd = rEnd

On Error Resume Next
Set col = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vStart)
    For J = vStart(I, 1) To vEnd(I, 1)
        col.Add Item:=J, Key:=CStr(J)
    Next J
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

UniqueDayCount = col.Count

End Function
```

Comment: Why not just calculate the difference between the lowest date on the left and the highest date on the right? `=MAX(B2:B500)-MIN(A2:A500)`
If you need VBA, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: So @RyanSimpson, the result needs to exclude days that do not occur at all in the "in between" ranges, that's basically the only problem left to solve, correct?

Comment: Your UDF is counting the number of days, and your simple formula is counting the days difference.  That will always differ by one.

Comment: @RikSportel, The UDF works perfect, but counts all "unique" days within the entered date ranges so when I use it for my example range it returns 14 and it should be 12. 

The reason i work out is 01/01/2018 is a unique date (but shouldn't generate any dwell time) and so is 12/01/2018. i need something that does what the UDF does, but without counting the first date.

Comment: One way of looking at it is that if someone started working on 1/1 and finished on 1/1, they worked for one day, but you are not counting that.  So what, exactly, is dwell time?  I've seen it defined as "time spent in a the same stage of a process", so it seems to me you should be counting 1/1 and not ignoring it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Exactly, As the task could be completed on the 1st and it was completed on the 1st there is no dwell time. Dwell time is not the amount of time it took to complete a task but the amount of time it took before completing the task based on the first possible day it could of been completed. I do not want to skew my project figures by classing tasks which have been completed on the same day they could have been as dwell time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your definition of dwell time, as not including the first day of work, I think all you need to do is modify your UDF so as to subtract a unique count of the start dates (and I'd probably rename the UDF as it is not really a UniqueDayCount):

### EDIT

*Based on your comments below, I have changed the algorithm.  I am using a `Dictionary` object as it is more flexible, and creating a list of both the unique dates, and a count of the overlap. Since the Start date of any process is not to be included, we exclude that first date of the process.  It seems to give the results you expect*

Note that I used early binding for the reference but, if this is going to be distributed, you may want to convert it to late binding.

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  or use Late Binding
Function UniqueDayCount(rStart As Range, rEnd As Range) As Long
    Dim dDTS As Dictionary
    Dim vStart As Variant, vEnd As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant
    Dim lDaysTot As Long

vStart = rStart
vEnd = rEnd

Set dDTS = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vStart, 1)
    If Not IsDate(vStart(I, 1)) Then Exit For
    For J = vStart(I, 1) To vEnd(I, 1)
        If Not J = vStart(I, 1) Then
        If Not dDTS.exists(J) Then
            dDTS.Add Key:=J, Item:=0
        Else
            dDTS(J) = dDTS(J) + 1
        End If
        End If
    Next J
    lDaysTot = lDaysTot + vEnd(I, 1) - vStart(I, 1)
Next I

I = 0
For Each V In dDTS.keys
    I = I + dDTS(V)
Next V

UniqueDayCount = lDaysTot - I

End Function
```

Comment: So i have given this a test with the following dates: 

A:01/01/2018 B:18/01/2018  
A:01/01/2018 B:19/01/2018  
A:19/01/2018 B:22/01/2018  
A:18/01/2018 B:23/01/2018  
A:20/01/2018 B:30/01/2018

which appears to now return a result of: 26

As you can see this should equal dwell time of 29 days as there were tasks running from 01/01/2018 - 30/01/2018. it would appear to me that if a date is in the Date A field it is now completely ignoring it from the calculation even if it appears in Date B.

Comment: @RyanSimpson Why would it be 29?  You wrote that you do **not** want to count the first day of a task as being included in the dwell time.  It would be 29 if there were only a single task, but you show multiple tasks.  (BTW, I am out of town so won't be able to respond quickly).

Comment: What appears to be happening is whatever date is included in the date A field (Cell A) is removed from the overlap calculation. The list of dates that i have used are put together so the tasks overlap to ensure the whole period of January from 1-30 is covered. The Key dates are: 01-19, 20-30 even if we do not include 01 or the 20 it should still return a value of 28 which it does.  But if another date range 10-20 is calculated, the values go down to 27.I can only assume this happens because date A is then ignored from the calculation. This is an issue because date range 01-19 covers this date.

Comment: Thank you Ron, This returns the results as expected and works so smoothly... I couldn't have got here without you and you've helped me learn a lot. I owe you a drink.